# Incredibly Quick Response From HR

Tags: consulting

I passed the screening and PST/online test for an engagement manager/project leader role for a top consulting firm in a matter of 3 working days. They got back 5 hours after I submitted a resume online, and 3 hours after I took the test.

Is this a sign they want me real bad, have nobody to hire, or that I applied to a phantom job posting which was just there for due diligence?

Comment: Guess! Why do you think anybody can actually answer this question?

Comment: Or you just did well and impressed them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be just a sign that this part of the process is automated to some extent.

If this is a "top consulting firm", then it's possible that they get a lot of applicants and they've bought an automated system for the first round of screenings.

Accept the response and carry on with the process.